# How to Push Value to an Array Inside an Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array inside an Object which looks like this.

```
sourceSystemArray = [{
  "attId" : 2257,
  "attributeName" : "country",
  "attributeValues" : [ "AU", "KG", "IN", "AF" ]
}]
```

Using input field I give user option to add a new Value.
Now I would like to finally add the New Input value that I get using `ngModel` to attributeValues array.
So suppose user enters a new Country say NZ.
So I want to push NZ to attributeValues and my final Object should like this:

```
sourceSystemArray = [{
      "attId" : 2257,
      "attributeName" : "country",
      "attributeValues" : [ "AU", "KG", "IN", "AF","NZ" ]
    }]
```

I tried using push method but it's not working.
Can someone help me figure out how to achieve it.

Comment: Do you means to push value into `attributeValues`?

Comment: What do u want to do? Not clear explain.

Comment: `???[0].attributeValues.push(something)` ... where `???` is the name of the variable that contains that Array you posted

Comment: If u create demo in StackBlitz we can find better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to add this object you might be having problems because it's in an array itself. Here's how I would add to `attributeValues`.

```js
let myarray = [{
  "attId" : 2257,
  "attributeName" : "country",
  "attributeValues" : [ "AU", "KG", "IN", "AF" ]
}]

myarray[0].attribute values.push('GB')
```

Or, assuming it's not the only item in the array.

```js
let myarray = [{
  "attId" : 2257,
  "attributeName" : "country",
  "attributeValues" : [ "AU", "KG", "IN", "AF" ]
}]

myarray.find(item => item.attId === 2257)
  .attributeValues.push('GB')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `sourceSystemArray` is an array, try this

```
sourceSystemArra[0].attributeValues.push("NZ");
```

Answer (score 0):

in html part u should send both attId and your new value with function

then in component u should find method with attId

```
function(attId,newValue){    
    this.sourceSystemArray.find(data=>data.attId ==attId).attributeValues.push(newValue);  
}
```